# Troubles with sessions

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing troubles with sessions codes

here is login code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @author Mina Wilson
 * @copyright 2012
 * // EPCI Pharma Survey | Rights Reserved
 */

 // Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if user is already login, then jump to secured page
if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
header('Location: login_process.php');
}
?>
<?php $login="login_process.php" ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>



<html>

<head>

<title>EPCI Pharma Survey</title>

<style>



html, body

{

    height: 100%;

}



body

{

    font: 12px 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;    

    margin: 0;

    background-color: #d9dee2;

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ebeef2), to(#d9dee2));

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ebeef2, #d9dee2);

    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ebeef2, #d9dee2);

    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ebeef2, #d9dee2);

    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ebeef2, #d9dee2);

    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ebeef2, #d9dee2);    

}



/*--------------------*/



#login

{

    background-color: #fff;

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#eee));

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);

    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);

    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);

    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);

    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);  

    height: 240px;

    width: 400px;

    margin: -150px 0 0 -230px;

    padding: 30px;

    position: absolute;

    top: 50%;

    left: 50%;

    z-index: 0;

    -moz-border-radius: 3px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;

    border-radius: 3px;  

    -webkit-box-shadow:

          0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),

          0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2),

          0 3px 0 #fff,

          0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2),

          0 6px 0 #fff,  

          0 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

    -moz-box-shadow:

          0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),  

          1px 1px   0 rgba(0,   0,   0,   .1),

          3px 3px   0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),

          4px 4px   0 rgba(0,   0,   0,   .1),

          6px 6px   0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1),  

          7px 7px   0 rgba(0,   0,   0,   .1);

    box-shadow:

          0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),  

          0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2),

          0 3px 0 #fff,

          0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2),

          0 6px 0 #fff,  

          0 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

}



#login:before

{

    content: '';

    position: absolute;

    z-index: -1;

    border: 1px dashed #ccc;

    top: 5px;

    bottom: 5px;

    left: 5px;

    right: 5px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;

    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff;

}



/*--------------------*/



h1

{

    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .7), 0px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);

    text-transform: uppercase;

    text-align: center;

    color: #666;

    margin: 0 0 30px 0;

    letter-spacing: 4px;

    font: normal 26px/1 Verdana, Helvetica;

    position: relative;

}



h1:after, h1:before

{

    background-color: #777;

    content: "";

    height: 1px;

    position: absolute;

    top: 15px;

    width: 120px;   

}



h1:after

{ 

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#777), to(#fff));

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #777, #fff);

    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #777, #fff);

    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #777, #fff);

    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #777, #fff);

    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #777, #fff);      

    right: 0;

}



h1:before

{

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, from(#777), to(#fff));

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #777, #fff);

    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #777, #fff);

    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #777, #fff);

    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, #777, #fff);

    background-image: linear-gradient(right, #777, #fff);

    left: 0;

}



/*--------------------*/



fieldset

{

    border: 0;

    padding: 0;

    margin: 0;

}



/*--------------------*/



#inputs input

{

    background: #f1f1f1 url(http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/login-sprite.png) no-repeat;

    padding: 15px 15px 15px 30px;

    margin: 0 0 10px 0;

    width: 353px; /* 353 + 2 + 45 = 400 */

    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    -moz-border-radius: 5px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

    border-radius: 5px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc inset, 0 1px 0 #fff;

}



#username

{

    background-position: 5px -2px !important;

}



#password

{

    background-position: 5px -52px !important;

}



#inputs input:focus

{

    background-color: #fff;

    border-color: #e8c291;

    outline: none;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e8c291 inset;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e8c291 inset;

    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e8c291 inset;

}



/*--------------------*/

#actions

{

    margin: 25px 0 0 0;

}



#submit

{       

    background-color: #ffb94b;

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fddb6f), to(#ffb94b));

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fddb6f, #ffb94b);

    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fddb6f, #ffb94b);

    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fddb6f, #ffb94b);

    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fddb6f, #ffb94b);

    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fddb6f, #ffb94b);



    -moz-border-radius: 3px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;

    border-radius: 3px;



    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);



     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;

     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;

     box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;    



    border-width: 1px;

    border-style: solid;

    border-color: #d69e31 #e3a037 #d5982d #e3a037;



    float: left;

    height: 35px;

    padding: 0;

    width: 120px;

    cursor: pointer;

    font: bold 15px Arial, Helvetica;

    color: #8f5a0a;

}



#submit:hover,#submit:focus

{       

    background-color: #fddb6f;

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffb94b), to(#fddb6f));

    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffb94b, #fddb6f);

    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffb94b, #fddb6f);

    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffb94b, #fddb6f);

    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffb94b, #fddb6f);

    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffb94b, #fddb6f);

}   



#submit:active

{       

    outline: none;



     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;

     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;

     box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;        

}



#submit::-moz-focus-inner

{

  border: none;

}



#actions a

{

    color: #3151A2;    

    float: right;

    line-height: 35px;

    margin-left: 10px;

}



/*--------------------*/



#back

{

    display: block;

    text-align: center;

    position: relative;

    top: 60px;

    color: #999;

}





</style>

</head>



<body>



<form action="<?php echo $login; ?>" class="input" method="post" id="login">

    <h1>EPCI Pharma Login</h1>

    <fieldset id="inputs">

        <input id="Name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" autofocus required>   

        <input id="Password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="actions">

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">

        <a href="">Forgot your password?</a><a href="">Register</a>

    </fieldset>

    <a href="#" id="back">Back to article...</a>

</form>






</body>

</html>
```

and here is login_process.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="ebarea_epic"; // Mysql username 
$password="..."; // Mysql password 
$db_name="ebarea_epic"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="medicalrep"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$name = stripslashes($name);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$job_title= stripslashes ($job_title);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE name='$name' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['name']=$array['name'];
$_SESSION['password']=$array['password'];


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password'];


if ($array['job_title']=="user")
{ header ("location: userpage.php"); }
     else if ($array['job_title']=="admin")
{ header ("location: adminpage.php"); }
   }
       else if ($name=="ahmedkamal8989@Epci" && $password=="epcisurvey2012@ahmed")
{ header ("location: adminpage.php"); }

    else {
  echo "Wrong user or password";
  }
?>
```

if the user and password are wrong, it shows " Wrong user and password ", by refresh the login form again it redirects me to login_process.php with message " Wrong user or password "

I've tried to change the echo to header and the location of the login form, but it caused a redirect loop

Now what's the problem!

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?  Can you reduce the possible causes of the problem at all, hopefully to some much smaller bit of your code than you have dumped above?  People are unlikely to read through all that, so it would help if you apply just a *little* bit of your understanding.  For example, do you really think the CSS is relevant to your problem?  And did you *really* intend to include the hardcoded (yes, hardcoded!?) admin username/password combo in your post?

Comment: Please try to eliminate non-relevant code when posting a question.

Comment: To clarify the comment @MarcusAdams, we don't need to see your CSS and the double spacing is unnecessary. Also, note that `stripslashes` is unnecessary if you're using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: var_dump($array) or print_r($array); tell us what you get. And you should remove the CSS part in the code above as it has no relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be [redirecting after every form post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

In this case, in login_process.php, instead of echoing "Wrong password" you should be setting a session variable something like:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "Wrong password";
```

Then redirect them back to the login page like this:

```
header("Location:/login.php", TRUE, 303);
```

On your login.php page, you should have something like this:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['message']; unset($_SESSION['message']); ?>
```

Comment: Good approach, I would just add a check `if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) echo ...` to avoid extraneous notices in case no message is defined in session.

Comment: @watcher, thanks, I considered that. I wanted to keep it simple for the OP. I tested it on PHP 5.3 and didn't get any warnings, but I'm not an expert on notices, warnings, and errors either. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with the important things in your PHP file

```
// username and password sent from form 
$name=$_POST['name']; //Save the post in $name
$password=$_POST['password']; //Save the post in $password

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE name='$name' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);


$_SESSION['name']=$array['name']; //OK you save the name in SESSION without knowing if the user has submitted the right login information
$_SESSION['password']=$array['password']; //OK you save the password in SESSION without knowing if the user has submitted the right login information


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result); //count always has to be 1 else failed login information

if($count==1){

$_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name']; //WHAT!?! override the SESSION with the post? without escaping?
$_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password']; //Same here!?!?!

//Now you decide the job_title
if ($array['job_title']=="user")
{ header ("location: userpage.php"); }
     else if ($array['job_title']=="admin")
{ header ("location: adminpage.php"); }
   }
       else if ($name=="ahmedkamal8989@Epci" && $password=="epcisurvey2012@ahmed")
{ header ("location: adminpage.php"); }

    else {
  echo "Wrong user or password";
  }
?>
```

So i made this code above like this

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="ebarea_epic"; // Mysql username 
$password="..."; // Mysql password 
$db_name="ebarea_epic"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="medicalrep"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT `job_title` FROM $tbl_name WHERE name='$name' and password='$password' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_results ==1)
{

$_SESSION['name']=$name;
$_SESSION['password']=$password;
$_SESSION['job_title']=$result[0];


switch($result[0])
{
   case 'user':
      $direct = 'userpage';
   break;

   case 'admin':
      $direct = 'adminpage';
   break;

   default:
      if ($name=="ahmedkamal8989@Epci" && $password=="epcisurvey2012@ahmed")
      {
          $direct = 'adminpage';
      }
      else
      {
          echo 'Wrong user or password';
          die();
      }
   break;
}

header('location: '.$direct.'.php');
die();

?>
```

I didnt test this, but i hope you can fixed the bugs yourself ;)